# Appending an modified user input to an existing text file

Tags: java

```
 package BIB;
 import java.io.*;
 import java.lang.*;
 public class fileParser{// start class file parser

       static Map<String, String> word ;
       Mapping_File mf = new Mapping_File();
       static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

       public static void main(String[] args){

            String Readline = "WCRE";
            String Converted = null;
            word = mf.getWordsMap();

            if(word.containsKey(Readline)){
                   Converted = word.get(Readline);          
             }

            else if(word.isEmpty()){
                 Converted = "the map you are looking in is empty";
              }

         `  else 
            {

                 System.out.println( "Couldnot find the elaborated form.
                                     Please Type the elaborated form you
                                   would like to use for : "
                            + Readline + "'");
                 String query  = scanner.next();
                 Writer output;
                 output = new BufferedWriter(new       
                              FileWriter("HashMap.txt",  true));
                 String Input = Readline + "=" + query;
                 output.append(Input);
                 output.close();
                 Converted = "Your Input was added to the mapping file";

            }// end else
            System.out.println( Converted);


     }// end main method
  }// end class
```

What I did here was created a file that is supposed to get elaborated form of an word "WCRE" from a mapping file Mapping_File that reads it from a text file. But the text file I have does not contain the word WCRE.

This program is supposed to ask user for the elaborated form because it does not exist in the text file I have, which it successfully does. Also the input user types is to be written in the text file along with the Words "WCRE=" before it.

However, when I run this code something like this is added to the end of file:

```
WCRE=ProceedingsWCRE=ofWCRE=20thWCRE=WorkingWCRE=ConferenceWCRE=onWCRE=ReverseWCRE=EngineeringWCRE=(WCRE)
```

What I want is:

WCRE=Proceedings of 20th Working Conference on Reverse Engineering (WCRE)

where "Proceedings of 20th Working Conference on Reverse Engineering (WCRE)" is user input.

The mapping file construct is following the mapping file works  fine while reading from the text file and creating a map

```
package BIB;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Mapping_File{

    static Map<String, String> words = new HashMap<>();


    public Mapping_File(){

        this.words = words;
        String filePath = "HashMap.txt";        
        String line;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try{

            reader =new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
            while((line = reader.readLine())!=null){
                String[] parts = line.split("=", 2);
                String key = parts[0];
                String value = parts[1];    
                words.put(key, value);

            }// end while
         }// end try block

         catch(Exception e){
               System.out.println("Couldnot find the requested file.");
           }// end catch block

         }// end constructor

        public Map<String, String> getWordsMap(){

             return words;
        }// end get method getWordsMap


}// end of class Mapping_file
```

The text file from which i am reading is following titled HashMap.txt :
ICSE=Proceedings of the International Conference on Software Engineering (ICSE)

IWSC=Proceedings of the International Workshop on Software Clones (IWSC)

ASE=Proceedings of the International Conference on Automated Software Engineering (ASE)

ACSAC=Proceedings of the Annual Computer Security Applications Conference (ACSAC)

ICSE (NIER Track)=Proceedings of the International Conference on Software Engineering (ICSE), NIER Track

Comment: whats `Converted`? please share the Mapping_File construct as well

Comment: are you even able to access `word` within the `main()`?

Comment: With word `static Map<String, String> word = new HashMap<String, String>() {{
        put("ICSE", "Proceedings of the International Conference on Software Engineering (ICSE)");
        put("IWSC", "Proceedings of the International Workshop on Software Clones (IWSC)");
        put("WCRE", "Proceedings of 20th Working Conference on Reverse Engineering (WCRE)");
    }};` like this. Your code in the fileParser class seems to be working fine. Just check if you are returning a correct map or not.

Comment: my teacher wants me to use a separate text file. I don't think i can do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The program worked on my computer when i declared Scanner inside  the main method. Scanner and also replaced scanner.next() with scanner.nextLine(), because i was supposed to read a whole line.